# passing double quotes to a command

Tags: powershell

I need to pass two double quotes as a parameter argument to the `pmrep assignpermission` command wherever the value 'NO_PERM' is encountered in the input CSV file. For some reason it's not working and is sending the empty string to the command.

```
$InputFile = Read-Host "Enter the Input File Name"
$CSVFile = Import-Csv "D:\$InputFile"
foreach ($Vals in $CSVFile) {
    $FolderName = $Vals.FOLDER_NAME
    $UserName = $Vals.USER_NAME
    $Permissions = $Vals.PERMISSIONS
    if ($Permissions -match "NO_PERM") {
        $Permissions1 = '""'
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
            & cmd.exe /c "D:\pmrep.exe AssignPermission"  -n "$FolderName" -g "$UserName" -p "$Permissions1" -o "Folder" -s "Native"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the complex invoking instead of calling `pmrep.exe` directly?

Comment: There is so many things wrong here. 1. Variables have to be passed to a scriptblock using `-Argumentlist` parameter. 2. And Scriptblock will need a `param` block. 3. You can invoke cmd directly like @vonPryz said unless you are going to run this on a remote machine using the `-Computername` parameter.

Comment: sorry I am a rookie in a PS world. I changed the script per VonPryz and it worked like charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$InputFile = Read-Host "Enter the Input File Name"
$CSVFile = Import-Csv "D:\$InputFile"
foreach ($Vals in $CSVFile) {
    $FolderName = $Vals.FOLDER_NAME
    $UserName = $Vals.USER_NAME
    $Permissions = $Vals.PERMISSIONS
    if ($Permissions -match "NO_PERM") {
        $Permissions1 = '""'
        & D:\pmrep.exe AssignPermission  -n "$FolderName" -g "$UserName" -p "$Permissions1" -o "Folder" -s "Native"
        }
    }
}
```